# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit) strange text appearing. Dell E5500

Tags: touchpad

I am an Ubuntu newbie. I find that intermittently, when I type text, a string of text that I did not type appears in the line. Sometimes it is a phrase that I may have typed in earlier in a different document; other times it is characters that I have not typed.

I have noticed this happening when I am using Google Docs in Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit).

I suspect it may be just me, mistyping by touching the pointing stick in the keyboard as I go.

Q: How can I disable the pointing stick?

I have already disabled the trackpad. I have already tried:

```
xinput -set-prop "DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0
```

and it could not find the device name.

Output from xinput is: `unable to find device DualPoint Stick`

I have disabled the trackpad in Settings but that does not disable the pointing stick.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from `xinput`? Did you first try `System Settings`, `Mouse & Touchpad` to see if it can be turned off there?

Answer (score 1):

The device name has changed. Type `xinput --list` to find the new name for "DualPoint Stick" and replacing it should solve the problem.

In my case the command is:
`xinput -set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0`